# Why does my function used to detect language work for my pandas dataframe but when wrapped in a UDF it doesn't work for my pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark, language-detection, cld3

I am using cld3 to detect language. I want to apply this to a column of a pyspark dataframe.
I am using databricks and this is the code I have right now:

```
def get_language(text):
  return (cld3.get_language(text)).language
get_language_udf = udf(lambda x: get_language(x))
```

when I apply the get_language function to the column in pandas format it runs smoothly like so:

```
pandas_dataframe['language']= pandas_dataframe['text'].apply(lambda x: get_language(x))
```

however, when I use the utf to create a new column in pyspark I get an error when I run this. here is the code:

```
pyspark_dataframe = pyspark_dataframe.withColumn("language", (get_language_udf(F.col("text"))))
display(pyspark_dataframe)
```

I have already installed and imported the cld3 library

any ideas what I can do to fix this? thank you in advance!

```
PythonException: 'pyspark.serializers.SerializationError: Caused by Traceback (most recent call last):
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 8.0 (TID 425) (100.64.38.7 executor 0): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'pyspark.serializers.SerializationError: Caused by Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 165, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 469, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 562, in subimport
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cld3''. Full traceback below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 165, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 469, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 562, in subimport
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cld3'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

pyspark.serializers.SerializationError: Caused by Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 165, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 469, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 562, in subimport
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cld3'


    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:689)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage7.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:758)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.$anonfun$processFunc$1(Collector.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:122)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:824)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1621)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:827)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:683)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2973)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2920)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2914)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2914)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1334)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3182)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3123)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3111)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:1096)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJobInternal(SparkContext.scala:2494)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.runSparkJobs(Collector.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.collect(Collector.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.InternalRowFormat$.collect(cachedSparkResults.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.InternalRowFormat$.collect(cachedSparkResults.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.collectResult$1(ResultCacheManager.scala:543)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.$anonfun$computeResult$1(ResultCacheManager.scala:550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.adaptive.AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.withFinalPlanUpdate(AdaptiveSparkPlanExec.scala:486)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.computeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.$anonfun$getOrComputeResultInternal$1(ResultCacheManager.scala:498)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResultInternal(ResultCacheManager.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:394)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectResult(SparkPlan.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectResult(Dataset.scala:3102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectResult$1(Dataset.scala:3093)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:854)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3898)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectResult(Dataset.scala:3092)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.OutputAggregator$.withOutputAggregation0(OutputAggregator.scala:268)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.OutputAggregator$.withOutputAggregation(OutputAggregator.scala:102)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocalBase.generateTableResult(PythonDriverLocalBase.scala:586)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.computeListResultsItem(PythonDriverLocal.scala:619)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocalBase.genListResults(PythonDriverLocalBase.scala:493)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.$anonfun$getResultBufferInternal$1(PythonDriverLocal.scala:674)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.withInterpLock(PythonDriverLocal.scala:555)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.getResultBufferInternal(PythonDriverLocal.scala:634)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.getResultBuffer(DriverLocal.scala:658)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.outputSuccess(PythonDriverLocal.scala:597)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.$anonfun$repl$6(PythonDriverLocal.scala:222)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.withInterpLock(PythonDriverLocal.scala:555)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocal.repl(PythonDriverLocal.scala:209)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.$anonfun$execute$11(DriverLocal.scala:549)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:215)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:210)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionContext(DriverLocal.scala:50)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:251)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:243)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.withAttributionTags(DriverLocal.scala:50)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal.execute(DriverLocal.scala:526)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.$anonfun$tryExecutingCommand$1(DriverWrapper.scala:693)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.tryExecutingCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:685)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.getCommandOutputAndError(DriverWrapper.scala:526)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.executeCommand(DriverWrapper.scala:638)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInnerLoop(DriverWrapper.scala:431)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.runInner(DriverWrapper.scala:374)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:225)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 'pyspark.serializers.SerializationError: Caused by Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 165, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 469, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 562, in subimport
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cld3''. Full traceback below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 165, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 469, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 562, in subimport
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cld3'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

pyspark.serializers.SerializationError: Caused by Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 165, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 469, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 562, in subimport
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cld3'


    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:689)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$2.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage7.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:758)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.$anonfun$processFunc$1(Collector.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$3(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.$anonfun$runTask$1(ResultTask.scala:75)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.$anonfun$run$1(Task.scala:122)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$13(Executor.scala:824)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1621)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:827)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.ExecutorFrameProfiler$.record(ExecutorFrameProfiler.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:683)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: How did you "install" `cld3` package?

Comment: %sh pip install pycld3

Comment: pip command will have a limited scope at the notebook level. If you're trying to use in a separate notebook you might want to install this at the databricks cluster libraries section.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Databricks, you have to go to Cluster configuration, then install `cld3` package there. This will install `cld3` on **all** the workers in the cluster, and you won't get that error anymore.

[image]